# Extract part of the strings with specific format

Tags: r, string, split

I am currently trying to crack the seemingly simple problem in R but somehow I am unable to find a way to do it with `gsub`, `str_match()` or some other `rgex`-related functions. Can anyone please help me crack this problem?

**Problem** Assuming that I have a column vector of certain length (say, 100). Each element in a vector has the form of `[string]_[string+number]_[someinfo]`. Now, I want to extract only the very first part of each element, namely the `[string]_[string+number]`. The potential upper bound on the number of characters in `[string]_[string+number]`, not including `_`, could be anywhere between **8 and 20**, but there is no fixed length. How can I use some types of `rgex` expression to do this in R?

```
x = c('XY_ABCD101_12_ACE', 'XZ_ACC122_100_BAN', 'XT_AAEEE100_12345_ABC', 'XKY_BBAAUUU124_100')
```

**Desired output.**

```
x1 = c('XY_ABCD101', 'XZ_ACC122', 'XT_AAEEE100', 'XKY_BBAAUUU124')
```

Comment: You might do us the favor of `x=c('XY_` , as this was likely intended.

Comment: @Chris I made that change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use a pattern to assert 9-21 chars to the right including the underscore, then the match the first 2 parts with the single underscore:

```
^(?=\\w{9,21}_[A-Z0-9])[A-Z]+_[A-Z0-9]+
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is to the right of the current location is

  - `\\w{9,21}_[A-Z0-9]` Match 9-21 word chars followed by an underscore and a char A-Z or a digit
- `)` Close the lookahead
- `[A-Z]+` Match 1+ chars A-Z
- `_` Match the first underscore
- `[A-Z0-9]+` Match 1+ chars A-Z or a digit

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BsTUMu/1) | [R demo](https://tio.run/##PY5BC8IgAIXv/QrZRWUO1NZhhxG6PAUdYsK2tiSG1KFgWNAg@u2mO3R733t88Jz3MyjBiGDTGiGrHaPMMG5EpSABsOlCqhjnhlFqpDgsZW2EUErFivF1voniMuxbI6UQWmvG86hAvHL2@ri8xpt9opmAQHaeHErOaFv2/ftTEM6@5iSyjmbFgGMY0j@nCQHBmqy7h5f1USuMvf8B)

```
x = c('XY_ABCD101_12_ACE', 'XZ_ACC122_100_BAN', 'XT_AAEEE100_12345_ABC', 'XKY_BBAAUUU124_100')
regmatches(x, regexpr("^(?=\\w{9,21}_[A-Z0-9])[A-Z]+_[A-Z0-9]+", x, perl = TRUE))
```

Output

```
[1] "XY_ABCD101"     "XZ_ACC122"      "XT_AAEEE100"    "XKY_BBAAUUU124"
```

Answer (score 4):

We could use `str_extract` from `stringr` package with the regex that matches to remove everything after the second underscore:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(x, "[^_]*_[^_]*")

[1] "XY_ABCD101"     "XZ_ACC122"      "XT_AAEEE100"    "XKY_BBAAUUU124"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(x, "[:alnum:]+_[:alnum:]+(?=_)")

[1] "XY_ABCD101"     "XZ_ACC122"     
[3] "XT_AAEEE100"    "XKY_BBAAUUU124"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
regmatches(x , regexpr("\\D+_\\D+\\d+" , x))
```

- Output

```
[1] "XY_ABCD101"     "XZ_ACC122"      "XT_AAEEE100"   
[4] "XKY_BBAAUUU124"
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I will test your suggested code. Why do we need `\\` before `D+` by the way?

Comment: `\\D` means Non-digits in string , and `\\d` means Digits; [0-9] ,  and `+` means Matches at least 1 time .

Comment: Wonderfully explained. Thank you so much! So it would fail if we have like `AB_123DE_NANANA`?

Comment: Usefully/interestingly, in this regmatches wrap approach, `'\\D+_\\D+\\d+'` and `'[^_]*_[^_]*'` are interchangeable.

Comment: As the `[^_` approach is generalized to `_` by position, it wouldn't fail such a change, likely, whereas \\D+\\d+ might have problems. Yup, more generalized wins.

Comment: You can use `regmatches(x , regexpr("\\D+_[A-Za-z0-9]+" , x))` in case of `AB_123DE_NANANA` it will not fall , give it a try .

Answer (score 2):

An option with `str_remove`

```
library(stringr)
str_remove(x, "_\\d+.*")
[1] "XY_ABCD101"     "XZ_ACC122"      "XT_AAEEE100"    "XKY_BBAAUUU124"
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your intended output strings always end with the last digital before `_`, you can try pattern `(?<=\\d)(?=_)` to find the position and remove the chars that follows

```
> gsub("(?<=\\d)(?=_).*$","",x,perl = TRUE)
[1] "XY_ABCD101"     "XZ_ACC122"      "XT_AAEEE100"    "XKY_BBAAUUU124"
```